# Setting variable in if statement not working

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

In this very simple makefile, I try to set a variable inside a condition, but outside the change is not noticed.

```
all:
        STUFF="nothing"
ifeq (true, true)
        echo "setting"
        STUFF="hi"
endif
        echo $(STUFF)
```

When I run this, I expect the last command to print "hi", but it doesn't.

```
chris@cranberry ~/git % make
STUFF="nothing"
echo "setting"
setting
STUFF="hi"
echo
```

What am I doing wrong here?

UPDATE:

```
run: build/aura.bin
    ifdef DEBUGGING
        $(eval DFLAGS=-s -S)
    endif
    qemu-system-i386 -serial stdio $(DFLAGS) -kernel build/aura.bin
```

Comment: As you've discovered, you can't set make variables directly in recipies. `eval` works but there's probably another way, unfortunately your example is too contrived to be able to give a decent solution, could you post how you really use this?

Comment: @user657267 See my updated question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this without `eval`

```
ifdef DEBUGGING
  run: private DFLAGS += -s -S
endif
run: build/aura.bin
    qemu-system-i386 -serial stdio $(DFLAGS) -kernel $<
```

Another alternative is

```
run: private DFLAGS += $(if $(DEBUGGING),-s -S)
run: build/aura.bin
    qemu-system-i386 -serial stdio $(DFLAGS) -kernel $<
```

Delete `private` to make the value of `DFLAGS` available in the prerequisites of `run`.

Comment: What's the `$<` for?

Comment: @chris13524 It's an [automatic variable](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Automatic-Variables), specifically `$<` expands to the first prerequisite, in this case `build/aura.bin`.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it by using `$(eval <statement>)` to set the values.

```
all:
        STUFF="nothing"
ifeq (true, true)
        echo "setting"
        $(eval STUFF="hi")
endif
        echo $(STUFF)
```

Comment: Rule of thumb: `eval` is never the right answer, unless there's no other possible answer.